# infinite series - can I just eliminate the constant to use p-series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

My particular question is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(2n+3)^{1/2}}$$

Can I say that as $n$ approaches $\infty$ the 3 becomes irrelevant, and hence I can just say:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt2n^{3/2}}$$

Then move out the $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ to use p-series and find that the series is convergent.

Is this valid work?

Comment: The usual way to go about this is to use the "limit comparison test": if $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are series of positive numbers, and $a_n/b_n\to1$ then either both series are convergent, or both are divergent.

Comment: @YadatiKiran Suuggest re-do above comment with MathJax fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple comparison test will suffice rather than a limit comparison test.  Note $$\frac{1}{n(2n+3)^{1/2}} < \frac{1}{n(2n)^{1/2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}n^{3/2}} < \frac{1}{n^{3/2}},$$ and since this last expression is the term for a $p$-series with $p > 1$, we find that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(2n+3)^{1/2}} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} < \infty.$$